# Integration of $\frac {1}{1+\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

For $\int \frac {1}{1+\sin x} \mathrm{d}x$, my calculus textbook told me to multiply the integrand by $\frac {1- \sin x}{1- \sin x}$ to obtain: $$ \int \frac{1-\sin x}{1-\sin^2 x} \mathrm{d}x= \int \frac{1-\sin x}{\cos^2 x} \mathrm{d}x$$

From here, it is a matter of breaking up the integral to two very trivial integrals, $\int \sec^2x \mathrm{d}x$ and $\int \sec x \tan x \mathrm{d}x$, which are easily found via commonly known rules.

My question is whether there exists a way of finding $\int \frac {1}{1+\sin x} \mathrm{d}x$ without having to perform the multiplication by $1- \sin x$ in the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Of course. The parametric substitution $t=\tan \frac x 2$, remembering that $\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$, $\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ transforms the integral in one of a rational function, which is computable through the usual algorithm. Multiplying by $\frac{1-\sin(x)}{1-\sin(x)}$ is much easier, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$. Then 
$$\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\mbox{ and }dx=\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}.$$
Then we can write 
$$\int\frac{1}{1+\sin x}dx=\int\frac{2}{(1+t)^2}dt.$$

Comment: Interesting use of trigonometric substitution. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can write $1+sinx=[cos(x/2)+sin(x/2)]^2$ that would also do.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$1+\sin(x) = \sin^2(x/2) + \cos^2(x/2) + 2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2) = \left(\cos(x/2)+\sin(x/2)\right)^2$$
Hence, we have
$$I = \int \dfrac{dx}{\left(\cos(x/2)+\sin(x/2)\right)^2} = \int \dfrac{\sec^2(x/2)}{(1+\tan(x/2))^2}dx$$
Setting $t=\tan(x/2)$, we obtain $2dt=\sec^2(x/2)dx$. Hence,
$$I = \int \dfrac{2dt}{(1+t)^2} = -\dfrac2{1+t} + c_1 =-\dfrac2{1+\tan(x/2)}+c_1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\dfrac{dx}{1+\sin x}= \int\dfrac{dx}{1+\cos\left(x-\dfrac{\pi}2\right)} = \int\dfrac{dx}{2cos^2\left(\dfrac x2-\dfrac{\pi}4\right)} = \tan\left(\dfrac x2-\dfrac{\pi}4\right)+C$$