# I have trouble while integrating $\tfrac{1}{1+\sin x}$ from $0$ to $\pi$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am getting trouble while integrating
$$
\int_0^\pi \! \frac{1}{1 + \sin x} \, \mathrm{d}x 
$$
by substituting $u$ as $\sin x$.

Comment: I am not understanting why

Comment: What doubt do you have?

Comment: Perhaps you may check for some other approaches in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576711/integration-of-frac-11-sin-x

Comment: One typical way to handle such integration is taking $1=\cos^2(x/2)+\sin^2(x/2)$ and $\sin x=2\cos (x/2)\sin(x/2)$, then you get a rational function on $\tan(x/2)$ with $\sec^2(x/2)$. From then you can substitute $\tan(x/2)$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1 + \sin x} 
&= \frac{1 - \sin x}{(1 + \sin x)(1 - \sin x)} \\[2pt]
&= \frac{1 - \sin x}{1 - \sin^2 x} \\[2pt]
&= \frac{1 - \sin x}{\cos^2 x} \\[2pt]
&= \frac{1}{\cos^2 x} - \frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x} \\[2pt] 
&= \sec^2 x - \sec x \tan x 
\end{align}

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you to notice that

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{1 + \sin(x)}\mathrm{d}x & = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{1 + 2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{(\cos(x/2) + \sin(x/2))^{2}}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{\cos^{2}(x/2)(1 + \tan(x/2))^{2}}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sec^{2}(x/2)}{(1 + \tan(x/2))^{2}}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1 + u)^{2}}\mathrm{d}u = 2
\end{align*}

Comment: Lovely. $\,\,\,$

Answer (score 2):

Exploit $\displaystyle \frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ (when $|x|<1$) to rewrite the integral in terms of the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), then utilize the power series derived [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4719133/170231):

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{1+\sin x} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^\pi \sin^n x \, dx \\
&= \Gamma\left(\frac12\right) \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac n2+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac n2+1\right)} \\
&= \sqrt\pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma(n+1)} - \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac32\right)}\right) \\
&= 2 \lim_{x\to1^-} \frac{\frac\pi2 - \arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $I$ denote the integral, and observe that, by symmetry,

$$I=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+\sin x}.$$

Furthermore, if $u=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}$, then

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1+\sin x}
&=\frac{1}{1+\sin\left(2u-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)} \\
&=\frac{1}{1-\cos2u} \\
&=\frac{1}{2\sin^2u} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin^2 u+\cos^2u}{\sin^2u} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}\left(\frac{-\cos u}{\sin u}\right) \\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}\left(\frac{1}{\tan u}\right)
\end{align*}

by recognizing the quotient rule, so

$$I=-2\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}\left(\frac{1}{\tan u}\right)~\mathrm{d}u=\frac{2}{\tan\frac{\pi}{4}}-\lim_{u\uparrow\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{\tan u}=2$$

by the FTC.